# Which statistical analysis replaces MANOVA when there are too many dependent variables?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, manova

I want to understand if an experiment gives equal response at two different levels of an experimental parameter. What I did was to repeat the experiment 6 times at the first level of the parameter and 6 times at the second level. The problem is that the experiment measures 20 variables, so I have 12 experiments and 20 measured variables. I'm not sure, but I think that MANOVA will not work in this setting.

Is this correct? What kind of alternative test should I use?

Comment: Interesting question. [This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.4547.pdf) looks like it could be relevant, but I have not looked into it yet.

Comment: Also, if you want to get some quick idea, you can (1) run 20 t-tests, one for each measured variable, (2) standardize all 20 variables, do PCA in this 20-dimensinal space, take the two first PCs, and look at the scatter-plot of your 12 points. Neither procedure is a statistical test you are looking for, but it can give you some idea about whether there is some difference or not.

Comment: See also [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3755504/).

Comment: Thanks. I had some fear to use PCA because I don't understand the possible effect of standardize the variables and of the choice of how many PCs to take. Thanks also for the references. I had a look at the first paper. It is interesting. I'll try the proposed test. I still have to read the second paper.

Comment: It would be great to hear from you how well these tests worked. I have briefly looked through both papers and could in principle write it down here as an answer, but I don't have any experience with either of these tests, so you might prefer to answer your own question after you tried them out. I also see that there is a large body of literature preceding these two papers starting with Dempster 1958 (citations are in the two papers above).

Comment: Note also that your situation (with only two groups) corresponds to Hotelling's test which is technically a simplest case of MANOVA, but to call it MANOVA might sound as an overkill. You might want to add `hotelling` tag and mention Hotelling's test in the title/body of your question (for future references and to attract more attention).

Answer (score 1):

If possible I would suggest first using either PCA to find a small number of composite variables or EFA to identify some latent variables. Then run the MANOVA on those components/factors to see if the experiment had an effect. Otherwise, when you test for group differences you (software) must estimate all of the 19*20/2 covariance parameters among the DVs and subsequently your power will be very low.